# Azure Auto scaling Metricshubs Active Cloud Monitoring

Tags: azure, cloud, autoscaling

I am using MetricsHub and I have an issue when upload my hosted services.

I get this following error :

"
The role's version of the Azure SDK is not supported
To use MetricsHub, your Azure SDK must be 1.3 or newer.

"

I don't understand why.

I have made a Maven Project and created a web application in java.

I already sent an email to support, but don't receive any response yet.

I tried to upgrade my sdk via eclipse but didn't work.

and add a dependency into pom.xml but didn't work

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.windowsazure</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-windowsazure-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please Help me . Thank you

Kenny

Answer (score 1):

I Found the solution to all my problems:

For the issue with the SDK:

- You have to upgrade the .NET SDK Version and not the Java one

Because when you build the project, Eclipse will execute the .NET SDK

Executing '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\2012-10\bin\cspack.exe" "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\CloudApp_Azure\ServiceDefinition.csdef" /role:WorkerRole1;"C:\Users\XXX\Documents\CloudApp_Azure\WorkerRole1\approot" /out:"C:\Users\XXX\Documents\CloudApp_Azure\deploy\WindowsAzurePackage.cspkg"'...

For the issue to enable Diagnostics in a project with Eclipse:

- You have to add this (in your serviceDefinition.csdef)

```
  <Import moduleName="Diagnostics"/>
```

```
  <Setting name="AutoscalingStorage"/>

  <Setting name="DataConnectionString"/>
```

- And this (in your serviceConfiguration.cscfg)

```
  <Setting name="AutoscalingStorage" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXX;AccountKey=YYY"/>

  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXX;AccountKey=YYY"/>

  <Setting name="DataConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXX;AccountKey=YYY"/>
```

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I think they ask you to install Windows Azure SDK for .NET instead of Java. Try download/install .NET SDK from here http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/

Comment: I have this following error now :

"Diagnostics disabled in Visual Studio"

I don't know how to do it because i developped a Maven project into Eclipse.

Kenny